# Hidden fields not submitting their values in Eureka swift form

Tags: swift, hidden, eureka-forms

I have a Eureka swift form that has a section of fields that we allow the user to show or hide. The problem is, when toggled to hidden, these fields do not submit their value when my form is submitted. Is there a way to hide a field yet still have it's values sent along with the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a `includeHidden` argument to the `values` method to get all the values including hidden ones as well:

```
let values = form.values(includeHidden: true)
```